# Flask/MongoDB - Data disappears when I refresh or interact with my website

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, web-testing

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on how to use flask.

The tutorial uses data created within the project folder, however I'd like to use MongoDB instead.

I've managed to connect to the MongoClient, and when the page first loads up, I get the wanted result. However, when I refresh the site, all the data disappears..

I've done some research, but the only thing I found that might help was to set form = false, but I don't know how to do that.

Here is my "app.py" file which I named "market":

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(debug=True)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template("home.html")

# Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.Marketplace
dbcol = db.items
cursor = dbcol.find({})

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    return render_template('market.html', items = cursor)
```

Here is my market.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Market Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Finn Plus</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Market</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <h1>Market Page</h1>
    <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- Your Columns HERE -->
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Barcode</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Your rows inside the table HERE: -->
            {% for item in items %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item._id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.barcode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }}$</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info">More Info</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-success">Purchase This Item</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    #<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    #<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->


  </body>
  <style>
      body {
          background-color: #212121;
          color: white;
      }
  </style>
</html>
```

In my MongoDB I have a collection called "items", with these documents:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "616f0c42ac33fbb995f3f70b"
    },
    "name": "Phone",
    "barcode": "12312VSD246",
    "price": 600
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "616f0c78ac33fbb995f3f70c"
    },
    "name": "Laptop",
    "barcode": "FGD653F212",
    "price": 749
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "616f0ca1ac33fbb995f3f70d"
    },
    "name": "Keyboard",
    "barcode": "54DFSDF12",
    "price": 139
}
```

When I try to run flask (set FLASK_APP=market.py, set FLASK_ENV=development, set FLASK_DEBUG=1, flask run), I get a successfull connection and the page that loads up looks like this:

[image: Website right after running flask]

I then hit refresh and everything data related from MongoDB disappears:

[image: Website after hitting refresh]

Any clues on why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `cursor` as a common variable for this instance of Flask development server. On the first call of `/market` the cursor variable is iterated, on the second the pointer is already at the end of the `find` results

You can try to modify:

```
Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.Marketplace
dbcol = db.items
cursor = dbcol.find({})

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    return render_template('market.html', items = cursor)
```

into :

```
# Database

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    db = client.Marketplace
    dbcol = db.items
    cursor = dbcol.find({})
    return render_template('market.html', items = cursor)
```

Not directly relevant for the question: For a better handling of Mongo session I advice you to have a look at flask_pymongo.